# Can I use the crushed remains of an old concrete slab as a base for a new slab?

Tags: concrete

I have recently broke up my old concrete shed base which was 100mm thick, I also have quite a lot of gravel. 
The broke up shed base is quite large chunks of concrete so could I use that a long with the gravel as a sub base for the new concrete base I am about to lay?
The chunks are a range of sizes from 20mm to about 90mm. Would it be ok for me to whack it down? Or should I just buy some proper stuff.
The new base is for our new summerhouse.

Thanks for looking.

Graham

Comment: This is the way road work is done... the old (concrete) road is broken up with a [sheeps foot road roller](https://becauseicantn.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/construction-equipment-101-the-sheeps-foot-roller/) and new concrete is poured on top.

Answer (score 7):

Crushed concrete is a very good substrate for a slab. The key is to not have chunks so large that air pockets are created. Maybe bring in a layer of sand to fill the voids and level things a bit. A water rinse will help bring air out and compact the material.